# How to pass the URI (location path) to proxy using nginx?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm using WordPress with nginx.

I need to set up 2 access locations:

> - mydomainname.com/ - nginx will return static files
> - mydomainname.com/wordpress - nginx will pass to PHP/WordPress

I have the following nginx config file:

```
    # https://mydomainname.com - Port 443 ===========================================
server {
    listen       127.0.0.1 ssl;
    server_name  mydomainname.com;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainname.com/fullchain.pem;
    include  /usr/local/nginx/conf/ssl.conf;
    location / {
        root /usr/local/www/mydomainname.com;
    index index.html;
    }


    index index.php;
    location /wordpress  {                           # I also tried "/wordpress/"
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /usr/local/www/mydomainname.com/wordpress;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I think I know the problem: The URI "/wordpress" or "/wordpress" is removed and not passed to PHP/Wordpress.

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the "/wordpress" or "/wordpress/" path to PHP/WordPress.

I'm tried proxy_pass but it does not work.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `root` statement into the `server` block and allow all location blocks to inherit the same value. Also, the WordPress URIs should be prefixed with `/wordpress/`.

For example:

```
root /usr/local/www/mydomainname.com;

location / {
    index index.html;
}

location /wordpress  {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
}
```

Comment: Well, I've tried it and that didn't work. And it looks like there is a typo try_files $uri =404;"".

Comment: I tried to work it out and I think it is not "try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;" because it is looking for a wordpress directory. It should be "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;" but passes the "wordpress" as the URI into the request. How do I do this?